# check for elements, if atleast 3 matches, then True

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I'm working an a problem, where I need to get 4 input from the user, and if atleast 3 matches, then the output is True. The only problem is I can only use logical operators(or, and, not, nor, nand, xor, etc.). I made it if 4 is on, but dont know how to do it for 3 without a complex code. Also can it be done without and if? Thanks.

```
tomb = []
for i in range(4):
    all = int(input("A kapcsoló állapota (1-fel, 0-le): "))
    tomb.append(all)
if tomb[0] and tomb[1] and tomb[2] and tomb[3]:
    print("Ég a lámpa")
else:
    print("Nem ég a lámpa")
```

Comment: *"I can only use logical operators"* – what exactly does that mean and why…?

Comment: The general logic is pretty simple: iterate through your input and count how many are "matching". That can be implemented in any number of ways: with a loop and incrementing an int, with filtering a list and checking its length…

Comment: *"if atleast 3 matches"* – what do they have to match with?

Comment: It's a task for a class. I can only compare the elements of the array with them.

Comment: @Diptangsu their value. The values can be only 1 or 0. And it's only True if there are three 1s atleast.

Comment: `("Nem ég a lámpa", "Ég a lámpa")[sum(bool(value) for value in tomb) >= 3]`. If the values can only be `0` or `1` you can use `("Nem ég a lámpa", "Ég a lámpa")[sum(tomb) >= 3]`

Comment: …convert the input to integers and sum them…

Answer (score 0):

You can count the answers and apply any threshold of matches that you would like:

```py
default_msg = 'Ég a lámpa'
threshold = 3
print(default_msg) if sum(tomb) >= threshold else print('Nem' + default_msg.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `all` function. The `all` function returns true if all the values are true. You don't have to do `tome[0] and tome[1] ...`.

Similarly `any` returns true if any of `tome[0] or tome[1] ...` is true.

```py
for i in range(3):
    ans = all(tome[:i] + tome[i+1:])

print(any(ans))
```

what this code does is iterate through all 3 combinations in your input and finds all the true triples and puts it in `ans`.